# SQL, count total users' first order for each region, each day

Tags: sql

I have a table called orders.
Link for the table here:
[table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UdgwUHtFGcb2cOzPBiAVI-hYzhyZnmAIob4HZcJ6WUw/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to get the total users' first order in each region, each day.
First, I tried to get the first order for each unique user by doing this:

```
SELECT  customer_id, 
        MIN(order_date) first_buy, 
        region
FROM orders
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

This resulted with:

```
customer_id, first_buy, region
BD-11500, 2017-01-02, Central
DB-13060, 2017-01-03, West
GW-14605, 2017-01-03, West
HR-14770, 2017-01-03, West
SC-20380, 2017-01-03, West
VF-21715, 2017-01-03, Central
```

And so on…
But I want to get this result:

```
first_buy, region, count_user
2017-01-02, Central, 1
2017-01-03, West, 4
2017-01-03, Central, 1
```

What do u think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to take the result you've got so far, then for each unique combination of `first_buy` and `region` (hint: or group), count the number of customers - so all you need to do is nest your current select inside another select that does just that.

Comment: thanks. It's done. Appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

It's done. Thanks to [@Lynn](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/135707/lynn)'s hint

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(t1.customer_id)), t1.first_buy, t1.region
FROM (
        SELECT  customer_id, 
                MIN(order_date) first_buy, 
                region
        FROM orders
        GROUP BY 1
        ORDER BY 2, 1
) t1
GROUP BY t1.first_buy, t1.region;
```